# what these dimensions represent in a neural network?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I am following the course of Andrew Ng on the topic of Deep Learning. In one programming assignment that uses the SIGN dataset. For what I know each image is composed of 64 by 64 pixels of width and height, and another dimension of 3 that corresponds to the RGB channels.

According to the author it says that the value of:

```
n_x=num_px * num_px = 64 * 64 * 3 = 12288
```

and having the following data:

```
number of training examples = 1080
number of test examples = 120
X_train shape: (12288, 1080)
Y_train shape: (6, 1080)
```

the part that I do not understand is when the author initializes the weights, he says that the shape of W1 (an array of weights) is:

```
W1 : [25, 12288]
```

this part I do not get it, why 25 as the number of rows? I get it that the number of columns corresponds to the formula of n_x, but this 25 to what it refers to? is it the number of neurons inside a hidden layer?

Thanks

Comment: `x*w^T == (n_samples, 12288)x(12288, 25) ==> (n_samples, 25)`. Although in tensorflow `w` is defined by `(12288, 25)` and not as the transposed matrix. Yes, 25 is the number of neurons in the layer

Comment: thank you @Vlad, but 25 refers to the number of neurons?

Comment: Yes, it is the number of neurons in the layer.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like `12288` is the number of input nodes and `25` is the number of nodes in the hidden layer.

Thus, the number of weights should be = `25` * `12288` (Each node in Layer(i) is connected to each node in Layer(i+1)), and thus the size of the matrix.